# Hiding Div by passing var to function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a nav menu and based on which item the user clicks i would like to show them a div, now my problem is, when they click a new menu the current div needs to be hidden again but i cant see how to pass the var through?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.submenu > li > a').click(function () {
        $('#' + lastClicked).hide(); // hides previous div
        var menu = $(this).prop('id') + "_view";
        $('#news').hide();
        $('#' + menu).toggleClass("hidden");
        var lastClicked = menu;
    });
});
```

I realize its because i'm not passing `lastClicked` back through, but how would i do this?

also when using toggleClass, i found the only was to pass in the property id is by doing '#'+menu, is this correct?

Comment: Remove `var` in line `var lastClicked = menu;` A guess

Comment: Can you please post your html code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

define lastClicked in a more global scope...

```
$(document).ready(function(){        
    var lastClicked = ''; 

    $('.submenu > li > a').click(function(){
        $('#'+lastClicked).hide(); // hides previous div
        var menu = $(this).prop('id') +"_view";

        $('#news').hide();
        $('#'+menu).toggleClass("hidden");
        lastClicked = menu;
    });
});
```

Comment: nitpick: that's not the global scope, but it is a scope outside of the click function, which will work for this purpose.

Comment: True... I'll fix that.